# How to correctly handle autorun start & stop on linux with python

Tags: python, linux, service, autorun

I have two scripts: "autorun.py" and "main.py". I added "autorun.py" as service to the autorun in my linux system. works perfectly!

Now my question is: When I want to launch "main.py" from my autorun script, and "main.py" will run forever, "autorun.py" never terminates as well! So when I do

```
sudo service autorun-test start
```

the command also never finishes!

How can I run "main.py" and then exit, and to finish it up, how can I then stop "main.py" when "autorun.py" is launched with the parameter "stop" ? (this is how all other services work I think)

**EDIT:**

Solution:

```
if sys.argv[1] == "start":
    print "Starting..."
    with daemon.DaemonContext(working_directory="/home/pi/python"):
        execfile("main.py")
else:
    pid = int(open("/home/pi/python/main.pid").read())
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 9)
        print "Stopped!"
    except:
        print "No process with PID "+str(pid)
```

Comment: Well, this isn't the design I suggested. If it works, fine. But you're not creating a pidfile, or a pid lockfile; you're relying on `main.py` being in the working directory; if the daemon is already running and you start it again you'll start another copy; your script probably isn't valid as an initscript on most platforms so you're still going to need a wrapper (to do status, return non-0 on error, etc., as well as to have the appropriate chkconfig comments)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're trying to create a system daemon, you almost certainly want to follow [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/), and you almost certainly want to use the [`daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) module to do that for you.

> When I want to launch "main.py" from my autorun script, and "main.py" will run forever, "autorun.py" never terminates as well!

You didn't say how you're running it. If you're doing anything that launches `main.py` as a child and waits (or, worse, tries to `import`/`execfile`/etc. in the same process), you can't do that. Either `autorun.py` has to launch and detach `main.py` (or do so indirectly via some external tool), or `main.py` has to daemonize when launched.

> how can I then stop "main.py" when "autorun.py" is launched with the parameter "stop" ?

You need some form of inter-process communication (IPC), and some way for `autorun` to find the right IPC channel to use.

If you're building a network server, the right answer might be to connect to it as a client. But otherwise, the simplest thing to do is `kill` the process with a signal.

If you're using the `daemon` module, it can easily map signals to callbacks. Or, if you don't need any cleanup, just use `SIGTERM`, which by default will abruptly terminate. If neither of those applies, you will have to set up a custom signal handler (and within that handler do something useful—e.g., set a flag that your main code checks periodically).

How do you know what process to send the signal to? The standard way to do this is to have `main.py` record its PID in a pidfile at startup. You read that pidfile, and signal whatever process is specified there. (If you get an error because there is no process with that PID, that just means the daemon already quit for some reason—possibly because of an unhandled exception, or even a segfault. You may want to log that, but treat the "stop" as successful otherwise.) Again, if you're using `daemon`, it does the pidfile stuff for you; if not, you have to do it yourself.

You may want to take a look at the service scripts for daemons that came with your computer. They're probably all written in bash rather than Python, but it's not that hard to figure out what they're doing. Or… just use one of them as a skeleton, in which case you don't really need *any* bash knowledge; it's just search-and-replace on the name.

If your distro has LSB-style init functions, you can use something like [this example](http://archives.aidanfindlater.com/blog/2009/09/04/sample-init-d-script/). That one does a whole lot more than you need to, but it's a good example of all of the details. Or do it all from scratch with something like [this example](http://werxltd.com/wp/2012/01/05/simple-init-d-script-template/). This one is doing the pidfile management and the backgrounding from the service script (turning a non-daemon program into a daemon), which you don't need if you're using `daemon` properly, and it's using SIGHUP instead of SIGTERM. You can google yourself for other examples of init.d service scripts.

But again, if you're just trying to do this for your own system, the best thing to do is look inside the /etc/init.d on your distro. There will be dozens of examples there, and 90% of them will be exactly the same except for the name of the daemon.

Comment: So, I have to place that code in "autorun.py" and modify it for my needs, right?

Comment: like this:
with daemon.DaemonContext(working_directory="/home/pi/python"):
    execfile("main.py")

Comment: Which code is "that code"? If you're asking about the `with daemon.DaemonContext()` no. If your `main.py` just defines and calls a function, all you need to do is replace `main()` `with daemon.DaemonContext(): main()` in `main.py`. If it's a big mess of module-level code, you may need a second file as wrapper. But (if I understand your design) `autorun.py` is _not_ a daemon, or that wrapper; it's a service script to _manage_ the daemon. In other words, it's the thing that gets the "start" or "stop" argument, right?

Comment: But, as I said, you probably don't want to use a Python script for the service script anyway. If you're just going to launch on `start` and kill -TERM on `stop`, a trivial bash script like all of the examples in your distro's `/etc/init.d` is all you need. For fancy cases like Apache, it's sometimes worth having the daemon, and a control program (which can start/stop/etc. the daemon), and making the service script a simple wrapper around the control program. But for your case, there's probably no need for that.

Comment: I have a simple "main.py" and I just want that to be run when the pc starts and if it's possible to stop and start it via "service ... start". I'm not very into deamons and services :/
But I placed `with daemon.DaemonContext(working_directory="/home/pi/python"): execfile("main.py")` in the "autorun.py" and it works good but only the problem that "service ... stop" just starts it a second time!
     A simple bash script would be better, yes I will also try that...

Comment: Is it enough when I write a bash script like `python /home/pi/python/main.py start` and `python /home/pi/python/main.py stop` ?

Comment: You can't have the same script be the wrapper for `main.py` and also be the service script for it. Again, if you can put all the top-level code in `main.py` inside the `with` statement, you don't need a wrapper at all, so you can trash autorun.py. If you need autorun.py, then for all intents and purposes, _it_ is the daemon. Either way, you still need to write a service script for whatever your daemon is.

Comment: But then the problem is again I can't start and stop it via "service ..." because the command waits for the process to terminate

Comment: No. First, a two-line bash script like that is just going to start and immediately stop. Except that running `main.py stop` won't stop an existing instance; it'll fire up a new instance and give it `stop` as its first argument, which won't do anything useful. You want something like [this](http://archives.aidanfindlater.com/blog/2009/09/04/sample-init-d-script/).

Comment: Okay so I will leave it as it is, but how do I let the daemon terminate? (SIGTERM is ok)

Comment: Something like that but much simpler! :P

Comment: I've edited the answer to give more info. But really, look at what's already on your system, as I suggested. It's a lot easier.

Comment: Okay I think it works now :)
I will post the code as edit in the main post.

Comment: It just terminates somehow after some seconds, but this is a fault in my script! Do you know if there's a log file where I could find the error logged?

Comment: By default, stderr doesn't get logged anywhere. But that's what the `stderr` parameter is for. You can do `with open(log_path, 'w') as logfile:` `with daemon.DaemonContext(stderr=logfile, …):` and if your program aborts with an exception (or does anything else that prints to stderr), it'll get appended to that logfile. For a more complex daemon, you might want to wrap a file-like object around `logging` or `syslog` instead of directly using a file, but for debugging simple cases, this is fine.

Comment: I used some try/catch statements :)